# Отключение от Wi-Fi сети с помощью iw

Tags: linux, сеть

Пытаюсь сделать дисконнект для активного соединения:

```
iw dev wlan0 disconnect
```

а так же:

```
systemctl stop wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
rm -f /opt/some_app/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Сообщений об ошибках нет, но если посмотреть с помощью

```
iw dev wlan0 info
```

информацию об интерфейсе - ssid никуда не исчез. Более того, если вместо `info` использовать `link` - то на выходе будут данные все той же сети, вместо ожидаемого *нет соединения*. Так же ОС ругнется на то, что в системе нет такого файла/директории (код:-2).

Подскажите, что можно сделать.

Comment: *ip link set dev wlan0 down* поможет?

Comment: @0andriy, спасибо большое, помогло! Вынесите в ответ, чтобы за ответ можно было принять)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы перевести сетевой интерфейс в неактивное состояние в Linux необходимо выполнить команду

```
ip link set dev wlan0 down
```

где `wlan0` имя сетевого интерфейса. Это работает на любых сетевых интерфейсах, будь-то Wi-Fi или обычная проводная сетевая карта Ethernet.